# start a batch file on startup as administrator on win 10

Tags: batch-file, service, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, startup

I want to disable auto-updating on Windows 10.
I found out that disabling the service "WINDOWS UPDATE" will do this.
It did for some time, but when ever i restart my system it enables itself again and again. So I created batch file that disables it.

```
@echo off

NET stop "Windows Update"
```

I put it in startup folder but it worked only if it is executed as administrator. I tried to set properties of the shortcut to "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR" but it stopped executing on startup.

Then I read about Task scheduler and added this task there but still its not working there even it just shows "The Directory Name is Invalid. (0x8007010B)

Comment: Download the software ShutUp10 by O&O (even recommended by some Microsoft forum mods) and deactivate the automatic updates. Free, clean and doesn't even need to be installed (works as portable).

Comment: Apart from the Windows Update service, there's also the Background Intelligent Transfer Service to stop so `Net Stop WUAuServ` followed by `Net Stop BITS` would be better. However the best method would be to use Group Policy and/or the registry.

Comment: I've posted on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/948069/174557) how to get control over automatic updates in Win10

Comment: Didn't worked for me....
There is somesoftware called *windows 10 update assistant* this is the one who is responsible I think.....and it installs itself when ever I tried to uninstall it...

Comment: use the 3rd party tool **Windows Update MiniTool** and set update mode to notification and here you can later select which updates you want to install, like in older windows versions.